# Global coordinated reminders

Tags: offline, cross-platform, reminders, app, random-number-generator

So... I have this **super obscure and specific** thing I'm looking for and I'm not very confident something like it even exists.

*I have created my own system which accomplishes this, but I would really like to hear if anyone knows any other systems/algorithms/apps/websites which achieve something similar to what I'm proposing below.*

Imagine there are 3 different collections of items/objects and a number representing how often each item should be featured by the system on average (in days). Each collection of items belongs to a different user. Users can have any number of items on the list.

```
1st user's items
XONOTIC 16
STACK_OVERFLOW 4
THE_MATRIX_1999 256

2rd user's items
YOUTUBE 2
CARDANO 32
ELON_MUSK 64
THE_DARK_KNIGHT_RISES_2012 512
RUST 64
XONOTIC 4
AREA_51 1024

3rd user's items
COREJOURNEY 64
XONOTIC 128
STACK_OVERFLOW 16
MINECRAFT 8
NO_BOILERPLATE 4
```

Certain items from the user's list are selected and shown to the user each day (respecting the user's numbers which determine how often each item should be selected/featured on average, in days). The items are selected randomly but if multiple users have the same item on their lists (in this example XONOTIC and STACK_OVERFLOW) - those items must be featured to all users who have them on their list on the exact same days. So, if there are 420 users who have WEED on their list of items - WEED should be selected and shown to all 420 of them on the same exact days. The software should achieve this kind of coordination using some kind of algorithm which is deterministic and works offline.

TLDR
**I'm looking for ANY website/program/app which does ANYTHING even remotely similar to what I'm describing.**
And I'm essentially describing a reminder app which coordinates global reminders about items users have on their list such that the same items have reminders/are featured on the same days for everyone.

EDIT
Here's the link to the system I created for this, if anyone's interested: https://github.com/TypicalHog/randevu
(I don't want this to come across as me shilling my thing, I'm genuinely interested if anything like this already exists)

Comment: Don't respecting each users different "priorities" stand opposite of the possibility of the system showing the same item to all users simultaneously?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Well, maybe. But when it comes to my system, I have mitigated that issue by making the "priority levels" powers of 2: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128... up to infinity. The trick is that an item will be "featured" with a different level of significance each day and all users whose "priority level" is lower or equal to the item's level will be "notified". For example, if a certain item is featured with significance of 16 - that means users who have it set to 16, 8, 4, 2 and 1 will be notified. And ones with a higher level would have to wait for the level to be higher. 1/2

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos This means people can choose to be reminded about something daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly, once every few years etc. (more or less, for example, 32 is not really monthly, but it's close enough, also, it's random and probabilistic, but it will average out to about 32 days over a long enough period of time).
So, people who have a lower level set for a certain item will all be getting notified on the same days, but for days where the item has a reminder 512 for example - everyone will get notified at the same time: people who have it at 512, 256... 4, 2, 1.
2/2

Comment: Ah I see. Never heard of such system. Sounds like something that could possibly be scripted into a [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com) based system, if one were to roll its sleeves up, being flexible as it is; but I don't know of any dedicated tool to do something like that.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yeah, I've never heard of anything similar either, hence the post. Here's the link to it in case you're curious: https://github.com/TypicalHog/randevu
I initially created it to feature random games, movies, websites, posts, videos etc. from my personal collection of them (each is a page in my own personal wiki), so the system features random items to me each day. But then I realized it could be used for featuring the same items for every single person in the world on the same days, which I think is very novel and powerful. 1/2

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos For example, people could add their favorite dead game (one with a fans but no active players cause they can never coordinate to come play it at the same time) and all of them could be reminded to come play it on the same days. Same for movies, posts or videos or anything, the system assigns special days to every object and users can add anything to their list and if enough of them do so, they can all coordinate to appreciate, play, discuss, remember etc. certain things every now and then - and everyone can choose if that's daily, monthly or idk decadely... as I said. 2/2

Comment: Sounds like a good way to meet or interact with like minded people. Particularly  interesting if it works offline, a rarity these days where everything mines your data and invades your privacy on every move.